# how to search for subclasses through an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Suppose we are designing a shop. Our shop contains many types of products(processors,screens etc.). We build an interface and prompt the user to give a specific type of product(ex. Processor) and th program should display all processors to the screen. There are 2 superclasses, peripherals and gadgets. All products are a subclass of one of the two. We have two arraylists(type peripheral,type gadget) that contain all products of each category. The question is: how to display **only** the products of the desired type.

Comment: Have you tried to solve the problem yourself? This looks like a homework assignment. We are not here to do your work for you. Read the SO guidelines before posting.

Comment: Use instanceof to check whether it is a gadget or peripheral

Comment: i have been trying to solve this for a few days. there are many subclasses, i "cannot" use instanceof that many times

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stackoverflow, we are able to help you, but we will not solve the problems instead of you, please read [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then feel free to edit your question regarding this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Using Java Streams:

```
myList
.stream()
.filter(item -> item instance of DesiredClass)
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Without streams:

```
for(Superclass item: myList){
  if(item instanceof DesiredClass){
    System.out.println(item.toString())
  }
}
```

**Edit 1:**

> yes i understand this way but a have too many desired classes so it's best I not use instance of

Ok but then you need to have a reference to the class that you want to show. I dont know how do you want to do it but for example you can have an enum with a `type` field with the class of each type of product. Then if you have the class you want to show in a variable like `Class type = ProductA.class;`

Using Java Streams:

```
myList
.stream()
.filter(item -> item.getClass().equals(type))
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Without streams:

```
for(Superclass item: myList){
  if(item.getClass().equals(type)){
    System.out.println(item.toString())
  }
}
```

**Edit 2:**

> how do you write this as a method

Ok so lets say you have an enum like this:

```
enum ProductType {
    PRODUCT_A(ProductA.class),
    PRODUCT_B(ProductB.class);

    public Class type;

    ProductTypes(Class type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

then your method would be:

```
void displayProductOfType(ProductType typeOfProduct, ArrayList<Product> list){
  Class typeClass = typeOfProduct.type;
  for(Product item: list){
    if(item.getClass().equals(typeClass)){
      System.out.println(item.toString())
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yes i understand this way but a have too many desired classes so it's best I not use instance of

Comment: how do you write this as a method(thanks for the help, I have tries it before and it didnt work for some reason, i dont get what variable type is)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using Java 1.8 streams, but the process is a little bit complicated. Since you have 2 superclasses and a lot of subclasses, you cannot use `instanceof` keyword. Now, that's when Java's Reflection API enters.
First of all, because there are 2 superclasses, you have to wrap them up to `Object` type in streams. To do that, you need this simple wrapper method:

```
public static <T> Object toObject(T obj) {
    return obj;
}
```

Next, you should use a `Map` to store the types of all subclasses with appropriate keys. The types of values in this map are `Class<?>`. Types of keys are up to you. Let's assume that they are `String`. For example, if users type "Processor", this should mean the type `Processor`. Create the map and put all of the subclasses with their keywords.

```
Map<String, Class<?>> types = new HashMap<>();

types.put("Processor", Processor.class);
// Other subclasses put here...
```

Here, you have two ArrayList's containing the products:

```
// Lists are not created here, you already have them
List<Peripheral> peripherals = new ArrayList<>();
List<Gadget> gadgets = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then, take user's input and query the map to get the desired type:

```
Class<?> desiredType = types.get("search_keyword");
```

Finally, combine two lists into one stream (with base type `Object`), and filter this stream to collect the products of desired type:

```
List<Object> processors = Stream
    .concat(peripherals.stream().map(p -> toObject(p)), gadgets.stream().map(g -> toObject(g)))
    .filter(obj -> desiredType.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Objects in this list are of the type user desires.